# how to use QWidget::scroll ( int dx, int dy ) in Qt?

Tags: qt

this is the [API document](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#scroll):

i am not sure how to use it, and what is effection it will work? the code i tested as follow:

```
#ifndef WIDGET_H
#define WIDGET_H

#include <QWidget>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:

};

#endif // WIDGET_H
```

> Widget.cpp

```
#include "Widget.h"
#include<QPushButton>

Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent)
{
    QPushButton* bt = new QPushButton(this);
    this->scroll(20, 0);
}
```

**there is no any change while delete `scroll(20, 0);` , can you help me , thank you!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QWidget::scroll() moves the widget's pixels that have *already* been drawn on the screen. This means that the function should be called after the widget been shown. In other words, not in the constructor. Consider this example:

header.h

```
#include <QtGui>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = 0) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        new QPushButton("Custom Widget", this);
    }
};

class Window : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Window()
    {
        QPushButton *button = new QPushButton("Button", this);
        widget = new Widget(this);
        widget->move(0, 50); // just moving this down the window
        widget->scroll(-20, 0); // does nothing! widget hasn't been drawn yet

        connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(onPushButtonPressed()));
    }

public slots:
    void onPushButtonPressed()
    {
        widget->scroll(-20, 0);
    }

private:
    Widget *widget;
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Window w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```